# How to get Facebook's access_token without browser redirection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, api

In my app I want just to get **access_token** and store it in database. But to get it, I need to specify **redirect_uri**. How can I do it without redirecting?

```
require 'httparty'

access_token = HTTParty.get('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token', {
    client_id: 'хххххххх',
    client_secret: 'хххххххх',
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    code: 'хххххххх'
})
```

Comment: You can't that is the whole idea

Comment: (re)read fb auth docs. they are kinda messy, but they will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. What you are trying to do is to login through Facebook, so you have to access their page to be able to do that.

Here's how OAuth works:

[image: OAuth Flow]